# How to auto call function in Kotlin for every function call within a class

Tags: kotlin

I have a class with multiple functions

```
class Foo() {
    fun one() {
        //do something
    }

    fun two() {
        // do something
    }

    fun three() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How can I trigger a call to a Logger object that I have, so that in the logs I can see all functions accessed or called, without explicitly placing the log call on every function to keep the code clean. I'm trying to keep a full log trace of all functions called within a service api call, but I don't want to have something like this

```
class Foo() {
    fun one() {
        log.call()
        //do something
    }

    fun two() {
        log.call()
        // do something
    }

    fun three() {
        log.call()
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, without explicitly writing the log statements.

Comment: Technically, you can, using a compiler plugin, but they are very little documented and complex to write.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in plain Kotlin.  But this is exactly the sort of thing [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) was intended for.

I haven't used it myself, but if you want to do it in Kotlin, you might look at [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html).  See also discussions [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/aop-and-kotlin/685) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364633/aspectj-doesnt-work-with-kotlin) question.

Comment: Thanks I'll check those out

Answer (score 1):

In Java I would write an IvocationHandler to create a dynamic proxy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327143/how-to-create-a-dynamic-proxy-in-kotlin-common-code)